# Logic Apps with Form Recogniser (Azure) - Error message: "ActionFailed. An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded."

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have created the logic app to read the invoice data using the form recogniser. When tested, I experienced an error. Any idea how this could be fixed?

Please see below my workflow and other details:

[image]

[image]

[image]

many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the official document from Microsoft, the Analyze form connector only supports PFD format and (JPEG or PNG) image formats. But, the attachment that has come from your email is an **octet-stream file** which is certainly not supported.

You need to ensure that you are supplying only the supported file formats.

Comment: Hi @Miles, glad it worked. Can you please mark my answer as accepted? so that, it will be helpful for other community members.